# Extract json data first level

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have the following webservice that returns a JSON response:

API signature: http://feiertage.jarmedia.de/api/?jahr=2016

I need to query the first level (where "BW","BB","BY"... are present) using `JSONPath`  well as the list of the names (e.g. "Neujahrstag", "Heilige Drei Könige").

Comment: Which language you are using or it does not matter?

Comment: `Object.keys(JSON.parse(json))`

Answer (score 0):

JsonPath.parse(yourJsonString).read("$[*]['name']")